# SSRS hide #Error

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression

I am getting an `#Error` on some cells after using the following expression, any ideas what's wrong with it?

```
=iif(Fields!PercentageCompleted.Value >= (ReportItems!ExpectedComplPercentage.Value) * 100, "Yes", "")
```

Comment: What are the values of `PercentageCompleted` that give an error?

Comment: PercentageCompleted is 50 and ExpectedComplPercentage is 0

Comment: What's the value of ReportItems!ExpectedComplPercentage when the error appears?

Answer (score 1):

The #Error code is a compiler error usually resulting in a type mismatch. If you have a value in one of those fields that VB.NET interprets as a string, it can't do a mathematical comparison and thus you get an error.

To fix this, use the CINT (integer) or CDEC (decimal) functions to cast the values to the data type you want. For reference, CSTR converts to string and CDATE to a date if you're trying to compare those later down the line.

```
=iif(CDEC(Fields!PercentageCompleted.Value) >= CDEC(ReportItems!ExpectedComplPercentage.Value) * 100, "Yes", "")
```

Note: I recommend you cast data types in your expressions pretty much all of the time to avoid problems.